# Is there a way to avoid division through size n in ift (ifft)?

Tags: fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Is there a way to avoid division through size n in ift (ifft) ?
Performing the Inverse (Fast) Fourier Transform on the complexnumbers, you go with a for loop through every element dividing it through the sizeof (dimension) of the array, to complete the last step of the inverse fourier transform.

Is there a (more efficient) way to go without it ?
Division is computationally expensive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: those who know, will know

Comment: multiply by the inverse.